# How Can I make it possible that my Text box will take only numbers and ,(coma) and spaace and + characters using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, client-side-validation

I am very bad at client side scripting. I am trying to use JQuery If possible. I have aspx page that has a web form with id = "formUI". This form contains multiple asp text boxes. One of them is (id=)txtPhone. This text-box will take one or more phone numbers separated by comma.I have link of jqury1.6.1.js and jqueryvalidator plugging in my aspx page.
How can I validate this Text field using jquery? I am looking forward for an easy and concrete solution from the talented coders of the community of stake overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values). This is a code on making textbox to accept only numbers. You can easily extend it to choose your needs. Also check this :[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in html inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for your this link, This is really cool. I got my solution and this is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: If this is the answer, then mark it as the answer, so that anyone else facing the same problem will know which one to use. :)

Comment: I am new to stake overflow, would you please tell me to make it as an answer? I hope I will get your Help In this Question also

Comment: There ll be a tick mark below the vote button of each answer. Just click the one near the answer you feel is correct to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('#txtPhone').keydown(function(event) {
    if(!$(this).val().test(/^[\d,\s+]*$/g))
       event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

of course create this function:

```
function fncInputNumericValuesOnly()
    {
        if(!(event.keyCode==45||event.keyCode==46||event.keyCode==48||event.keyCode==49||event.keyCode==50||event.keyCode==51||event.keyCode==52||event.keyCode==53||event.keyCode==54||event.keyCode==55||event.keyCode==56||event.keyCode==57))
        {
            event.returnValue=false;
        }
    }
```

and call it with:

```
onkeypress= "fncInputNumericValuesOnly('txtQty')"
```

Comment: i think u need to use onkeydown cause it fires before the press so it will prevent the character to be puten in the textbox

Comment: no because you call it in the textbox like this <input type="text" onkeypress= "fncInputNumericValuesOnly('txtQty')">

Comment: u maybe right but this will be workin only on IE cause in FF event must be passed in the event it self like 

onkeypress="fncInputNumericValuesOnly(event);" then catch it in side the function then deal with it

Comment: i'm sure its not workin in FF cause there is no event object can be call directly in the js function it must be passed through the function :) u try it

Comment: maybe you right XD I'm sorry call this function adding on the top a "getElementById("MyId").value();"

Comment: @Friz14 and @Marwan: Thnanx for your nice arguments. A logical and structured argument can be as good as a tutorial.